# Mootools catch form data on submit on the same page

Tags: javascript, forms, try-catch, submit, mootools

This one's been breaking my brain.

I'm trying to fetch the $_POST data from a form and put that in a div on the same page as the form using Ajax in the mootools framework. And i cannot get it to work, the succes message shows, the div only gets filled with: Array().

The php file is simple:

```
<?php
 print "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
 ?>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('form-booking').addEvent('submit', function(event) {
    event.stop();

    var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');


    this.set('send',{
      url: this.get("action"),
      data: this,
      update: log,    
      onComplete: function(response) { log.removeClass('ajax-loading');   
      alert('Succesvol aangevraagd.'); $('log').setStyle('background','#ffffff');

      }
    }).send();
  });
});
```

UPDATE

```
Header:
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Fri, 09 Mar 2012 12:06:17 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Location    http://192.168.52.64/xampp/
Server  Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l   mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.1
```

POST:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [date_from] => 1331300252
    [service_check_8] => 1
    [service_check_34] => 1
    [booking_form] => 1
    [cnt_nights] => 7
    [cnt_person] => 2
    [cnt_children] => 0
    [cnt_baby] => 0
    [child_ages] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 2
            [12] => 2
            [13] => 2
            [14] => 2
            [15] => 2
            [16] => 2
            [17] => 2
            [18] => 2
            [19] => 2
        )

    [service_cnt_8] => 2
    [subservice_16] => 614
    [service_cnt_34] => 1
    [subservice_40] => 301
    [subservice_88] => 688
    [service_cnt_67] => 1
    [subservice_122] => 762
    [service_cnt_68] => 1
    [subservice_123] => 765
)
</pre>
```

Comment: it means that the `$_POST` array is empty, 1.) what do you see when you submit the form without ajax (directly to the action page) 2.) use firebug (or similar) to see what data is being sent 2.) try using `$_REQUEST` to make sure you'd not making a `GET` request

Comment: 1) i see the array i expected, with the post data. 2) how can i get firebug to show that? 3) how do you mean, kinda new to Ajax.

Comment: $_REQUEST is PHP, d'uh, time for coffee;) I tried both GET and POST in te php file, no result, however.

Comment: can you post the header including the data posted to the action url (e.g. from firebug)

Comment: See above post. Hope this was what you meant?

Comment: Updated the post as given in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Please next time, do a bit of better job with formatting your code - this is quite hard to read ... could you try this (exactly as posted)

```
$('form-booking').addEvent('submit', function(e) {

    new Event(e).stop();

    var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');

    this.send({
        update: log,
        onComplete: function() {
            log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: new Event(e).stop() ? this is code for mootools 1.11, events are 'normalised' since 1.2.1 to contain all the methods you'd expect

Comment: I'll try that next time, the editor and me had an arguement. The code provided as above, does nothinhg, but no erros also.

Comment: Well, still nothing further with this, and it's driving me nuts. I'm also beginning to think tha t mootools is a dying or about to be extinct language? As there is no actual support anymore on the forums or anything. In there is just one guy who doe his best to answer.

Comment: Any particular reason you chose mootools? Any chance of switching to jQuery - it has much better support

Comment: Well, the website came using mootools, i am now looking @ Jquery, but i'm wondering if it can be combined?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Array()' is coming from php - you need to change some things in your code:

First of all, add a `method: post` to where you set send. PHP is printing your $_POST array, which is empty, so you get exactly the response you are seeing. This is not a mootools problem.

Also, your $('log').setStyle... won't work because your log div seems to have the id 'log_res' (unless you have 2 different log elements going on).